# Is It possible to find out why I was systematically downvoted?

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

Seems to me that [I was systematically downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/3834?StartDate=2010-01-13&EndDate=2010-01-13), is it possible to find out who did it? 
[image]

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23005/i-think-i-was-just-serial-downvoted-how-can-this-prevented-by-the-community and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes and many many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a trend. Wait 24 hours, they should all be reversed if they fit the mass-downvoting profiler.

As for who did it, that is the problem with anonymous voting. It is anonymous.

While you waiting, you and [this guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35358/is-it-ok-in-the-rules-to-have-someone-go-through-all-of-your-posts-and-downvot), can go hate the world together :)