# Someone downvoted all of my questions and answers, what should I do?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, voting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)
>   [I keep getting downvoted, does someone hate me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39696/i-keep-getting-downvoted-does-someone-hate-me)

So someone went through and downvoted all of my questions and answers last night for some reason.

How do I go about getting help on this issue and also restoring my reputation?

Comment: yea i just didn't know what to search for, sorry about that

Comment: @Gramm, no worries.

Comment: Suffer, but only for a short time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called 'Serial Downvoting', See my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim/28758#28758).