# More often than not if someone down votes me I get +9 rep! Is that right?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we reduce rep bonus for upvotes on posts with a negative score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score)

A lot of users will up vote if they see a question or answer that has -1 but is not totally terrible.  So you then have (-1 + 10) = 8 rep.

> So an answer that should have got no
>   rep, gets +8 rep, due to the helpful
>   person that down votes it.   (Thanks
>   for the down-votes, they give me lots
>   of rep!)

What if instead we said:

```
If (totalVotesForItem => 0)
   repGained = totalVotesForItem * 10
Else
   repGained = totalVotesForItem * -1
```

Then getting one down vote and one up vote will give 0 rep gain rather than 9 rep gain.

Comment: Related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased

Comment: Wouldn't it give +8 rep? It cost 1 to downvote someone, but the receiver gets -2.

Comment: This is only the tip of the iceberg. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20084/generating-reputation-through-downvotes

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score

Comment: ps, thanks for the down vote, that got me a upvote and +8 on this question.  Can I other another down vote please so I get +16...

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be a better solution to just increase the cost of down votes?

It looks like this is already in the works:

> [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/)

Comment: It would seem that way, but that feature has been frozen to 0 Kelvin for months.

Comment: Maybe we should wake it up!

Comment: that only works if the person that is down voted loses 10 rep for each downvote they get.

Comment: @Ian: That sounds like a good idea.