# Possible to search questions I voted on?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, search

I couldn't find any hint if it is possible to search for questions I voted on.

The only workaround I can think of is to add all those questions to my favorites but I'd like to distinguish between those I generally consider being good questions and those I find particulary usefull (mostly because of the answers to those questions).

---

**Update**

Since this question keeps getting upvotes (and duplicates pointing to it) I'll turn it into a feature-request.

---

**Revisited**

Since the discussion on [social media sharing icons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136760/143302) cropped up I figured that sharing questions and answers would be the most flexible way to have categorized bookmarks ("Non-Freehand-circle answers I downvoted").

**I'd drop this request if I could share anything without copy/pasting from the *link* box.**

Comment: I often wish to refind something I saw on SO and thought was great, therefore I would like the normal search to put results I upvoted at the top, but still give me all the normal search tools.   (Now also make this work from google...)

Comment: There is a browsable list in the votes tab in your profile now/again. It's not searchable though (except for ctrl f and hoping you're on the right page)

Comment: @BenBrocka I think the social-media-sharing/bookmarking will be more flexible than the lists in my profile. I regret that I didn't take the opportunity to categorize my posts but this is also partly due to the fact that I wanted to bookmark and categorize other peoples posts rather than my own.

Comment: Has there been any traction on this? I'd like to be able to locate the questions I've already voted on.

Comment: @JoshDM I adopted the social media "share" functionality (g+) and am quite content with that since it gives a lot flexibility to categorize questions and answers even beyond "questions I voted on".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible because I believe there's no way to search for questions you voted on, period. I remember reading that in reference to the electorate badge; I'll see if I can find a reference.

EDIT: I can't (easily) find a reference other than [this answer by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-badge-progress-pundit-etc-too/34440#34440) in regards to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-badge-progress-pundit-etc-too):

> Some of the badges are supposed to be
>   surprises, not World of Warcraft style
>   level grinds based on numbers.
>
> I worry that if we provide too many
>   metrics:
>
> - it becomes noise, like a bunch of
>     inscrutable F-16 cockpit gauges -- how
>     are all these numbers useful except
>     for these specific badges?
> - the badge
>     becomes the explicit goal instead of
>     the desired behavior
> - the badges are no
>     longer a pleasant surprise and reward
>     but an expected "level up""

That doesn't specifically answer your question. To throw in my $0.02, I think being able to view all the questions you've voted on would be a useful feature.

Comment: The data dumps don't allow searching by votes, because that would mean making your vote history public. This doesn't mean the interface couldn't show you *your* vote history.

Answer (score -1):

There used to be a "votes" tab on the user page which showed you everything you voted on.. but we dropped it due to disinterest, and because it was a poor early substitute for proper Favoriting support.

Comment: Okay, since I'm not even a "yearling" I never got to see this tab. If an according feature request pops up I'll jump in.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to favoriting, at all.  I voted for something earlier today, I'd like to go back and see what it was (fixed it on one machine, need to fix it on a different machine), but it's not something I'd call a "favorite" answer.  In fact, I'd go so far as to say that I don't see the point of "favorites" at all - they're a weird early version of voting, and now that you have voting you can get rid of favorites.

Comment: I agree with @James Moore.  I remembered that I upvoted something recently, but it wasn't necessarily a favorite.  I would like to see what it was that I upvoted.  Also, I can only favorite quetions, not answers.  I want to see the answers I upvoted.

Comment: Ever since I started using Stack Exchange for about 3 years ago, I believe that "votes" tab has existed, so it seems like this answer is rather obsolete.