# Is it possible with SEDE to get a list of another user's posts that I have upvoted?

Tags: support, data-explorer, up-votes

I'm interested in obtaining a list of all the posts by a specific user that I have upvoted.  Is this possible?

Although I don't have much experience with the Data Explorer, I am aware that the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) exists and will be happy to learn how to use it.  However, before I begin, I'm wondering if that sort of query is even possible.

If someone has already crafted a query that does this, I'd love to find it.  Alternatively, perhaps there is a way to do this via the search function on a site, without using Data Explorer.  I'd love to learn about that, as well.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure this would be possible since you could theoretically put in any user's ID and get the posts they've voted for, which is private.

Comment: @Jamal That's what made me think this might not be possible.  Although, I don't know how Data Explorer works.  If I am logged in as myself, do I have access to my own vote data that other users don't have access to?

Comment: Information about who votes for which posts is private, you won't find that in the data explorer.

Comment: Keep in mind that all queries are public and cannot be linked to a non-SEDE account (and you can see that SEDE account interfaces are quite different from regular ones).

Comment: Not in SEDE, but on your profile page there is a "votes" sub tab. That what you were looking for?

Comment: @Oded Yes, I've seen the votes tab. It shows me question titles, but I have to click through each one to find out if it's a Q or A and find out who posted it. And I've voted over 2900 times on my most active site....

Comment: This feature request seems related: [Possible to search questions I voted on?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48830).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Individuals' votes are not included in the data dumps or SEDE, so you can't query this information.  A general rule of thumb is that any information not publicly available is not included.  The data is the same for everybody; it's not like logging in to an SE site and seeing your private information on your profile.

The votes that are available are things like close votes, delete votes, favorites, bounties, and the like.  (Yeah, you might not think of all of those things as votes, but I suppose we're seeing an implementation here.)  Not up/down votes.

Comment: That's what I suspected, thanks. Are there any tricks you know of for searching through your own upvotes on your profile?

Comment: @BenMiller beyond the tabs for different types of votes, no -- it's rather a pain to find things that way, particular older votes.

Comment: By the way, thank you for your work on the SEDE tutorial.  It has been very helpful, and I've had fun writing a few queries to answer some of my own questions.

Comment: @BenMiller I'm glad to hear it's helping you.  Thanks!