# Can upvotes be sorted and searched?

Tags: support, voting, search

I am constantly wanting to back through helpful questions and answers that I remember, and upvote, so I can reference and view them multiple times, continuing to get benefit from them.

The search bar has great functionality in giving you the post you are looking for, but I still find myself going to *profile > votes* to view previously helpful posts.

[image: votes tab]
Unfortunately, I have found I will 'hesitate' to upvote a good answer so as to not clutter this "votes" tab with posts that I don't see as having timeless, reusable value.

It seems that these votes are sorted automatically by recent activity first, and can be filtered by upvote, downvote, etc... but sometimes I would like to search by keyword or tags.

How do others save and lookup canonical or personally beneficial posts that they benefit from multiple times?

Thanks

Comment: This feature request seems related: [Possible to search questions I voted on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48830) Some of the [posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/48830) might be of interest, too.

Comment: Yes, it seems that question is a duplicate I missed while searching. It sounds like OP has some sort of workaround with sharing via Google+, as it seems shared links can be indexed. Will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to search questions I voted on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48830/possible-to-search-questions-i-voted-on)

Comment: It turns out "Bookmarks" is quite useful in this regard.