# Should one upvote if the downvote was unjustified in a not so good/bad question?

Tags: discussion, ethics

If one sees people downvoting a not-so-bad question, should one upvote it to nullify it in that same not-so-good question?

Comment: While it's frowned upon to upvote to offset a downvote, the choice is yours. Nobody can tell you how to vote as long as it's not abusive.

Comment: Do you think that the post is helpful/useful?  If so upvote.  Do you think that the post is not helpful or not useful?  If so, downvote.  If you are not sure, or cannot decide, don't vote at all.

Comment: It would need far more downvotes for me to consider adjusting the score of this question.

Comment: Is there a particular question you had in mind?

Comment: These are called sympathy votes. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93356/is-there-an-actual-pity-or-sympathy-upvote-problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38595/sympathy-upvote-problem-on-questions

Comment: If you do, you should leave a comment along the lines of *"+1 because although this question something-or-other-based-on-downvote-reason, I don't think it deserves so many downvotes"*. This way the point the downvoters were trying to make is still clear, and the OP knows that the upvote was only because you think the score is wrong, and not that the question is good and doesn't need fixing.

Comment: I'm sorry *"I don't think it deserves the downvote"* is a cop out. You've decided not to figure out for yourself if the question is worthy of an upvote and instead just blindly canceled out the opinion of someone who took the trouble.

Answer (score 14):

It's your decision. There are no rules for upvoting except that you can't serially vote/vote maliciously.

In my opinion, however, I think you should not, as upvotes have more weight than downvotes (they are worth more rep).

Also, the mouse over text for the upvote button mentions many things, but not "this post does not deserve downvotes."

In summary, technically you **can**, but it is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends. Some questions/answers are simply downvoted because they don't follow the basic F.A.Q rules. Some are downvoted because of the content which is totally of subject or misleading.
It may not be a good idea to go against the downvotes in such a situation.

But there are so many different possibilities that we can't simply say you *should* or *should not* upvote a previously downvoted question/answer. So it's totally up to you.

Also, it is to be noted that on a site like Meta, some questions can be answered with an opinion which is more likely to get different reactions (good and bad) from users. Take one of my answers as an example :

> [image]

Comment: Needs more inception

Comment: @FrankstonRalphingtonIII haha thought about it for a few seconds too... I wanted to go change my answer for triple answers in answer...