# Different implementation of downvoting: require comments

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

OK, I know this has been discussed before [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes), [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/require-comments-on-downvotes-closed) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59736/penalise-downvotes-without-comment-reward-downvotes-with-comments-closed) but I'd like to make a new suggestion.

**Problem:** drive-by downvoting - people downvote without explaining why. And when you downvote, legitimately, you lose rep, as does the questioner / answerer. This strikes me as being a lose / lose situation.

**Previous solutions:** e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/require-comments-on-downvotes-closed) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59736/penalise-downvotes-without-comment-reward-downvotes-with-comments-closed) have required forcing comments.

**Solution:** How about this instead: keep the current system (downvoter loses rep) **unless the downvoter adds a comment** in which case no rep is lost. I think this is win/win. The downvoter can *choose* to enter comments but is encouraged to do so, which increases the feedback to the original questioner / answerer.

Comment: except for the -2/-1 instead of -1/±0, I don't see the difference between this suggestion and your [second example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59736/penalise-downvotes-without-comment-reward-downvotes-with-comments-closed) -- in particular, that one does *not* require forcing comments.

Comment: @balpha - yes, it is similar. I was thrown by the **closed as exact duplicate** banner (which it wasn't). But I don't think the proposal *as stated there* is very clear, to be honest.

Comment: Holy Unicorns and Waffles, Batman! (random comment so I don't lose reputation).

Comment: @George - if this was implemented I would flag (see comment on Chris's answer). So that "objection" is easily overcome.

Comment: @Mark Still pointless; see George's comment above

Comment: This variation has been part of the discussion on most of the previous rounds. Nothing to see here, folks. Move along! Move along!

Comment: @dmckee - I appreciate that this has been discussed before but there is a reason why it keeps being discussed i.e. that the current situation can be improved. This is a simple *extra option* which I think will help.

Comment: @NullUserException - I don't understand, my comment *was* about George's response.

Comment: @Mark I think his point is, you can leave a random comment that is not obviously random, but doesn't explain the downvote either.

Comment: @NullUserException - yes, I got that, but my point was you can **flag it**. If the comment was then removed (as in the current flagging process) then *the downvoter would lose rep as if they had not commented*.

Comment: @Mark Huh, what's stopping me from downvoting and then commenting "Why is this being downvoted?" Or even "Great answer!"

Comment: @Mark: You have *not* proposed a new option. The comment-or-cost variation has been brought up before. In addition to the links you provide there was extensive discussion related to [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/) which [included this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased/7329#7329).

Comment: Can't find or link to it anymore, but AFAIK this was actually one of the first suggestions thrown out on UserVoice way back when. It's an appealing suggestion - *if* you assume that folks will never *ever* be motivated to subvert the system. And yes, this keeps coming back up @Mark, but just because there are aspects of the current system that make some folks unhappy doesn't mean a change will necessarily be any better.

Comment: @dmckee - I stand corrected. The suggestion you mention is indeed the same with, an interesting observeration by Jon Skeet to take upvoting of comments into consideration. That leaves me with two questions: 1. Why was that not implemented (I can't see that in the comments there)? and 2. Why is this post attracting downvotes whereas that one was received very positively (including the supporting comments)? Or is this herd instinct http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63387/does-herd-behavior-influence-the-so-sites (joke). =:-)

Comment: @Mark: The one I linked had a *big* crowd of participants there to protest the proposed increase in the downvote power. Many of those folks weren't the meta regulars and presumably don't keep on eagle eye on this site. Given time more of them are likely to find you proposal here. But it won't help because you can't force a *useful* comment. If the mods are willing to punish non-sense comments you will simply drive *careful lying*. It's trivial to write some vaguely related war story or a pedantic note about history or suggest a grammar or vocabulary change.

Comment: @dmckee - I take your point, but if we only built sites to cater for the "problem people" then this site and others, like Wikipedia, wouldn't ever work. I think the benefits outweigh the cost but, probably like all the other contributors here, it's just a guess unless we try.

Comment: @Mark: your whole suggestion is built around the assumption that you can force users who aren't behaving "properly" to do so by changing how they're rewarded. Obviously, folks *can and do* downvote and comment already. So you're hoping these "problem users" will do likewise with the proper rewards in place... But I suspect it's far more likely they'll continue to behave as they already do, with perhaps a bit of extra noise thrown out to recoup lost rep. Look around SO - do you really think people with something to say are holding back because the site doesn't reward them enough for speaking?

Comment: tkmhekdjm hdmjkddfsd

Comment: @Kop - that was tried by George (see above) and I said those comments would be flagged.

Comment: I don't understand why we couldn't implement this. Either leave a comment when downvoting or upvote an existing comment. In fact, I don't understand the arguement against this.

Comment: @Some Free Mason: It *could* be implemented, but is it going to be worth the trouble? I think not. Plus, people will do anything to save every iota of rep. If posting a comment - even if it's nonsense - means they get to keep that 1 rep, then so be it.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn It's not about rep, it's about the OP understanding why his question is bad.  PLUS it also prohibits people from downvoting because they don't like the TYPE of question but instead downvote for a specific reason.  See Christianity.SE for examples of questions that get downvoted because of the TYPE fo question vs quality of question.

Comment: @Some Free Mason: "It's not about rep" In an ideal world, everyone would agree, but in reality, a large portion of users don't. Anybody is free to comment to say "-1 because I don't like this question" or "-1 because your face" and they'll automatically be exempted from the rep loss.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn "-1 because your face" will be flagged and then removed. But you knew that, right?

Comment: @Wikis: So is the rep penalty supposed to be applied retroactively when it gets removed? That just reinforces my opinion that having rep penalties (or rep gains or any form of rep change for that matter) be tied to comments is far too much work for too little gain - whether they're nonsense or reasonable, well-meant advice doesn't do anything to help the nature of comments which is their sheer *fragility*. And now I don't even know why I bothered typing this response after ignoring this thread for days but whatever, since I've typed it out might as well post it.

Comment: @Wikis: (nothing personal of course, I just don't think it's worth discussing beyond "comments are too fragile for any of this to be meaningful")

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - since you're not sure whether you should have responded I'm not sure whether I should respond... :) But we have retroactive rep changes all the time, from people undoing down votes after a post is improved to questions being deleted... I can't imagine it is "far too much work" - but then I don't work on the code.

Comment: Down-voting is useless without feedback. *Completely and utterly useless.* Gibberish comments, revenge down-voting, and so on -- all the many different arguments I've seen against requiring comments on down-votes -- are handled better by the community policing itself, which can only be done when all feedback is subject to review and further feedback.

Comment: *Something* is needed to put a stop to arbitrary/revenge/attack downvotes.

Answer (score 18):

It has been discussed multiple times, and I'm certain this is actually repeating things I have read from [a resident sage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/a-resident-rolling-head). Probably in way too many words, though.

Downvotes and comments are completely separate entities. They are not, and should not, be associated! There are way too many holes that are present in this kind of solution, all of which ultimately do not reward explaining the downvote.

In a much more difficult example than what [ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66020/different-implementation-of-downvoting-require-comments/66022#66022) provides, suppose someone downvotes and leaves a comment along the lines of "Why are people downvoting this answer?". You can stop complete gibberish, but you can't differentiate otherwise legitimate comments without betraying anonymity.

More problematic is the fact that this system will imply that the presence of a comment about the problems of a post indicates a downvote was cast by that user. We already have problems with this association being made, and revenge downvotes miscast to otherwise helpful and innocent bystanders.

To conclude, there's also a noise production. Sometimes downvoters don't comment because someone else addressed it already. You'll promote people to post "me too" and "Like @dood said, fix your post" comments, which should be flagged and deleted. And under your system, this means they don't get their reputation back, despite explicitly explaining why they downvoted.

Comment: *We can't equate comments and down-votes. Because comments don't equate to down-votes. Down-votes are not a tool that can be used to imply comments. As I have answered in comments-and-down-votes questions here so many times before...* (oh, not *that* resident sage)

Comment: Thanks for the constructive answer. I have a few comments & questions: 1. "you can't differentiate otherwise legitimate comments without betraying anonymity" not sure what you mean here - the anonymity of downvoting? Perhaps **downvoting should not be anonymous**? That would solve the issue in your fourth paragraph. 2. Your last paragraph raises (for me) an interesting issue: should then people downvote if their reason for downvoting is already added? Perhaps someone could, after downvoting, then click on an existing reason?

Comment: Downvoting is a privilege one pays for and a responsibility that one takes. Garbage comments are cleaned up no matter what (eventually).

Comment: @Mark: there's a difference between saying, "We'll clean up the garbage" and saying that while adding "...so please, when you have some, always throw it on the ground so we know what you've been up to." The former is fine; the latter is... stupid. We don't need to spend more time picking up crap after folks who should know better just to prove to ourselves that they're alive.

Comment: Fair enough but we can hand them a garbage bag instead of directing them to the bin across the room. Put a text box right there or a list of radio buttons. I don't want to look for a comment box. I'm not a fan of minimum entry lengths, either.

Comment: How about this?  Downvoting costs the normal -2 rep, if the downvoter leaves no comment.  If a comment is left, it only costs -1 rep.  If the comment receives an up-vote, the point received from that upvote cancels out the -1, win-win-win :)

Answer (score 5):

> This strikes me as being a lose / lose situation.

It's not a lose-lose situation. Stackoverflow (the community) wins.

Comment: @BalusC - No, it is lose / lose if: 1. people downvote without explaining why (how can you learn?) and 2. people DON'T downvote because they'll lose rep.

Comment: @Mark: the primary purpose of voting is to rate posts. If you want to instruct or correct, use comments. Currently, you can instruct or correct without rating, and you can rate without instructing - **this is a very good arrangement,** because instruction can be time-consuming and difficult, but the site depends on quick-and-easy rating in order to collect enough data to properly sort posts. Equate the two, and one or both uses suffer.

Comment: @Mark: don't you generalize "people" a bit too much? There are certainly users who downvote.

Comment: @BalusC - I don't understand your comment. Was it intended as humour?

Comment: @Mark: it was targeting on point 2 in your first comment.

Comment: @Shog9 - but my point was that the current system is still kept - you can still choose not to comment. But if you do you don't lose rep.

Comment: @BalusC - sorry, still don't get it. My point is that people can do one of two things (not explain or not downvote) - both of which are not good.

Comment: @Mark: there are other problems with encouraging commenting like that, most of which have been discussed to death (and then discussed again above). BalusC's point - which I support - is that comment-free rep-costing down-votes provide a valuable service to the site as a whole, encouraging motivated users to rate posts. Binding comments into this changes the whole dynamic.

Comment: @Shog9 - I agree that "comment-free rep-costing down-votes provide a valuable service" - but at what cost? Is it a more valuable service than *not comment free*? We don't know - we can't know, unless we try. Otherwise we are just guessing instead of producing objective data.

Comment: @Mark: by that rationale, we should change how voting works every few weeks, so as to collect better data on which configuration works best. But, that would be chaos. The first question you should ask of any proposed change is, "What problem does it solve?" - in this case, I don't see a problem.

Comment: @Shog9 - I think that, by that rationale you try different things and see what works best. And you remain open to try new things (admittedly, within reason - which avoids chaos). As to the problem, I highlighted that in my question - drive by downvoting. No one learns from that (except perhaps fearing of challenging the status quo).

Comment: @Mark I fail to see how a system that doesn't actually change what happens to a drive-by downvoter is a solution to drive-by downvoting.

Comment: @Mark: we may have to just disagree on this, but again, I do not believe that "drive by" down-voting is a problem any more than "drive by" *up-* voting is a problem. If every vote on the site required a comment, the noise would be deafening, good comments buried under bad ones. But once you accept that quietly voting and moving on is acceptable in some situations, you're free to reflect on the situations where commenting *actually makes sense*... without dragging voting along for the ride.

Comment: @Grace Note - it just tips the balance in favor of not drive-by downvoting. It won't eliminate the problem - just reduce it.

Comment: @Shog9 - you may be right about agreeing to disagree. Your comment about comparing it to upvoting is a good one. But upvoting is always (I think) pleasantly received but downvoting is not - hence this request. And (I'm probably repeating myself) - you can *still* downvote and move on - that's not changed by my proposal. But, OK, fair enough, maybe it's time to get on with our real lives... :)

Comment: @Mark: there you hit on the crux of the matter: anonymous up-votes don't irritate or hurt feelings, but anonymous down-votes do. Neither one requires any thought or explanation, and indeed up-votes are free and so presumably require *less* consideration... But down-votes create noise here on Meta because folks get hung up on them. Whether or not changing that is worth the cost will depend greatly on how you see voting fit into the site as a whole.

Comment: @Shog9 - well, we can probably agree on that at least... :)

Answer (score 3):

This idea has been discussed in answers to my question on [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes).

The basic problem is what is there to stop someone entering "afkhshsgklh" any other meaningless phrase as the comment?

Comment: @ChrisF - I didn't see this specific idea discussed - maybe I didn't read far enough down the answers. But the solution is simple - those answers get flagged and, when they are removed, the downvoter still gets the rep hit.

Comment: @Mark - I've just double checked and I can't find it in my question either, but I know it has been discussed.

Comment: @ChrisF I thought we agreed on "I don't like your gravatar" and ["-1 my cat's breath smells like cat food"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59162/statler-and-waldorf-badge-for-explaining-downvotes/59165#59165)?

Comment: there is also the problem of "-1 for the same reason as ... mentioned", should that be indicated by an great-comment-vote? But that could basically mean anything

Comment: Flag the comments as abuse; and the user will be ding 100 points when 5 people do so.

Comment: @Software Actually, the comment flag threshold is based on the number of comment upvotes it gets. And unlike upvotes, flags age away. So circumstances can lead to such comments sticking around.

Comment: The purpose is to provide constructive criticism. You can do that anyway in a comment. I think you should do but it might not necessarily be made a "requirement"

Comment: ....actually you CAN stop people from entering in nonsense by creating a file with nonsense entries and disallowing those entries from being entered in.  A similar file , actually similar fileS are used in Wikipedia to stop creating of wiki entries ( even variations on the name ) and user names ( again even variations of the user names).    This would actually work here.  I support it, especially as a new editor, it would be helpful for me to learn why I was being downvoted.

Comment: Addendum: The other objection I've seen to this is "someone already gave that explanation".  While  it's true that we shouldn't have the same explanation twice, if someone's already explained that , however, if that 's true then there's no reason to downvote it again for that same reason.