# StackExchange Community Behavior

Tags: discussion

Why is a very large portion of members of this community so obnoxious?

Downvoting people's questions or putting them "on hold" with no additional information; marking it as "too broad", for example, which I 've seen many times while the question is very very clear! My guess is that these people are either too bored to bother or lack the wits to *try* to understand the questions.

Common courtesy is a no-go on this community and basic interaction shows us that most of the "experts" here are just pretentious snobs, which is very disappointing. What good is it for us when only a 5-10% (of what I've encountered to be fair) of the users are polite to others?

The "possible duplicate" states clearly that it "aims" a specific question. I am talking about the general behavior of this community.

Comment: Is there any point to this rant?

Comment: Plenty of reasons actually, rant is not that polite either which kind if proves my point, take a look around and see that new users get "ToS-Bullied" all the damn time.

Comment: What do you want from us? Effect some kind of change? Make a proposition to deal with what you think is a problem. Just insulting members on meta does nothing for your percieved problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Is on-topicness in the ToS? And "Why is there life on Earth?" is a clear question, yet too broad. This should be closed as off-topic anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [We need to be a little less hostile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181040/we-need-to-be-a-little-less-hostile)

Comment: This community is kind of unique in that we don't care about you as a person in the slightest, only about the quality of the content you submit. Submit a bad question, it will get downvoted. And wether or not a question is very clear or straight forward is often not as clear-cut as you seem to think, especially if you are the asker.

Comment: Then why create a community? Community is something that involves social skills which apparently many people lack. Just as I said, pretentious snobs that probably think they are too good for the rest of the world. What if I told you that you can be smart and polite at the same time?

Comment: @Karaflakos: Just think if your comments have been polite. Was your question polite? Is calling people "pretentious snobs" polite?

Comment: @Karaflakos SE sites are mostly useful Q/A ressources, and communities a distant second. Actually impolite comments are very rare on SE, but I can see you percieving "Thats not how you ask here, please read $helpcenter and $howtoask before posting again or edit your question" as impolite. Fact of the matter is, you are not the judge wether you posted a decent question, the other members are. If you find genuenly mean comments, you can flag them.

Comment: Caring about Q/A quality first doesn't make us "pretentious snobs", its actually the purpose of this site

Comment: If you think you have seen it `many times` why don't you provide links to the questions you are talking about?

Comment: Did you maybe hit a bug? Because when a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1344221) is closed as *too broad* I do get a post notice that says: *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.
If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.*. Maybe that guidance is not clear enough to what your next step should be? I don't leave comments because I assume the post notice serves as such.

Comment: Oh dear god, I am saying that you do not even *TRY* to understand someone's question if it takes a second time to read it, some people make grammatical mistakes or spell a word word and you are about to burn them on a stake. In fact the comments that are immediately trying to deflect the accusation are those who are actually doing what I am saying in my initial question. Caring about quality is not bad, but when something is wrong you can always say "what do you mean by that, or fix this" not just flag a question and leave.

Comment: @christian do you want me to re-search for question I ve seen in the past two years? Most of them will not even be there because some people delete them plus I cannot even recall what they were about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)

Comment: You do know that "put on hold" is supposed to be temporary, right? When a question gets made better by edits, it can be (and often is) reopened. If a question is currently unanswerable then the right thing to do is put it on hold until OP adds necessary details. Then it can be reopened.

Comment: @rene just a notification that it's been on hold and what for, no guidelines. For the asker a question is already pretty specific, the one that reads the question is the one that has to say "i do not understand this specific part, please rephrase?" or sth like that imo, otherwise how will the asker know what to change?

Comment: @Karaflakos : If you think this behavior is very frequent it shouldn't take you long to find three examples. That would make the discussion more specific.

Comment: @Karaflakos I think that is noise but I noted your concern, thanks for pointing that out to me. I'll do my best to be more helpful to this community in the future.

Comment: @rene thank *you* for being polite enough to care about someone's concern!

Comment: As being said a lot, this is all about content. I'm not downvoting or closevoting *you*. I'm downvoting the content. A downvote on Jon Skeet's post is the same as a downvote on a 1 rep user's. Write bad content, get the downvotes. Write good content, get the upvotes. If anyone takes downvotes personally, the problem is they didn't understand the philosophy behind downvotes.

Comment: @IͶΔ Guys my point is that some people hit and run, on a 10min post you may see 5 upvotes and no additional info. Why is this considered as acceptable , I find it completely impolite and annoying, if you don't like my question or don't understand it why is it such a big deal to leave a comment explaining your action?

Comment: @Kara the problem is we can do nothing systematic to require people to explain their votes. If we required them to explain their reasoning, we would've ended up with gibberish comments all along the site, with nothing more than "asdfasdfasdfasdf" in them. We all agree that people that explain votes are awesome people, but not everyone is awesome. Many people are just normal. On the other hand, *some* people have grown tired of others revenge-downvoting them when they revealed that they're the downvoter with explanation of their vote in a comment.

Comment: And as usual, it's up to the established community to help each and every user with all their questions.  That doesn't scale.  That **never** scales.  We should be helping everyone that spends zero effort trying to learn and adapt?  That seems like a wasted effort.  I will help those that **try**.  Attacking the community for curating their sites makes the rest of your argument moot.  Unless you're receptive, there's no point in even trying.

Comment: @INΔ you are right man! Never thought it that way, I got angry with that situation I felt I should make a topic about it. I don't mean to insult anyone personally, but I am really sorry if I offended anyone. Should I delete the question or just leave it as is?

Answer (score 14):

> Why is a very large portion of members of this community so obnoxious?

I would like to know particularly why you feel so. I don't think merely closing questions makes people obnoxious, as curating the site by closing bad questions is one of the central duties of user-driven moderation as practiced on StackExchange.

> Downvoting people's questions or putting them "on hold" with no
>   additional information;

Recieving a downvote carries some information, from the sidebar:

**"This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear, or not useful."**

Thats the implicit message that a downvote carries. No comment is necessary to convey that. Furthermore, if your question is put on hold, users are required to choose from a variety of very specific reasons as to why in their closing votes. You can see the reason that was chosen in the yellow box that indicates a question has been put on hold.

> I 've seen many times while the question is very very clear!

If you think so, you can exercise your own community moderation by either upvoting it or (when you get higher rep) nominating it for reopening.

> My guess is that these people are either too bored to bother or lack
>   the wits to try to understand the questions.

Thats a pretty unsubstantiated guess at that. Closing unclear or bad questions is a main part of the user driven moderation here, and makes the Q/A of the site (which is its main purpose) clearer and reduces noise between decent posts.

> Common courtesy is a no-go on this community

One of the strictest enforced policys on here is the "Be nice" policy, which mandates civility in comments and communications. If you find legit mean comments, you can flag them (15 rep required).

> basic interaction shows us that most of the "experts" here are just
>   pretentious snobs, which is very disappointing. What good is it for us
>   when only a 5-10% (of what I've encountered to be fair) of the users
>   are polite to others?

Thats again a very unsubstantiated claim and in and of itself kind of a violation of the "be nice policy".

Answer (score 10):

One of the reasons Stack Exchange works is the very narrow, almost laser like, focus on a specific topic.

The reason this is important is because we need experts to answer the questions, and if they have to wade through questions that aren't on topic or are poorly written, they will leave.

I understand that this appears to be discourteous or even snobbish, but hopefully you understand that it's important to our community to keep these experts engaged and feeling like they aren't wasting their time.  They are unpaid, after all, volunteering their time to help people out for fake internet points.

There are many, many forums available for people who want to talk about other things, or want to communicate using poorly written questions.

This simply isn't one of them, and honestly I think that's one of the main reasons the site is so valuable and useful.