# How many downvotes for a question are enough?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

Suppose I read a question that has a net vote level of -3.  Maybe it's even been flagged.  Would it be overkill to downvote it?  Does the answer depend on whether it's a brand-new user?

Is there a negative number at which you would hesitate to downvote?

In minigolf, there's usually a suggested maximum number of strokes per hole, to prevent people from getting too discouraged.

Comment: Why should there be *enough*? Downvotes are indicating a post's quality. They're not aimed at anyone or anything. They're not personal. You should comment as say so if the OP feels attacked.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M - So there's no lower bound?  ----  I don't see the purpose in going more and more negative for a new user -- but I haven't figured out when enough is enough.

Comment: There is no fixed lower bound. If you however feel uncomfortable downvoting a contribution, then don't. It's that simple.

Comment: @Bart - What lower bound do experienced users have, that they use to decide when to stop piling more downvotes on a brand-new user?

Comment: Nothing that we could inform you of. There is no set lower bound. Generally a couple of downvotes is all something will get. Sometimes a bit more if it gets a lot of attention. And on rare occasions something gets utterly nuked. It all depends. Generally upvotes far outweigh downvotes. Don't look for a fixed number. Just vote how you see fit.

Comment: Why should there be a lower bound if there's no upper bound. And if there is an upper bound how would you distinguish posts at that upper bound. Equally how would we indicate the difference between that's a bit silly and that's absolutely crazy and dangerous if there was a lower bound.

Comment: see also: [Finding a way to discourage users from downvoting questions that have -8 DV's already?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179453/165773)

Comment: Whether a member is new or not is irrelevant, as irrelevant as the amount of downvotes already present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm leaving Meta sites out completely here, as voting on those is very different.

---

> I don't see the purpose in going more and more negative for a new user
>   -- but I haven't figured out when enough is enough

There is no one "limit" or "threshold" to suit all questions or scenarios.
Decisions on voting are not just black and white, as there are often varying parameters in deciding whether to vote up or down, vote at all, comment instead, etc.

I don't think we should be "soft" on new users, otherwise they won't get the message.
If they post a poor question and only receive 1 downvote, they just think it's one user who's an idiot, or whatever.
But I also don't think we should downvote them to hell - as long as they're polite and at least trying a little bit.

Being new to Stack can be hard, confusing, and even frustrating, but this does not warrant nor excuse a terrible attitude.

So if a new user's question is poor, terrible even, but the user is making even a basic level of effort, I'm more likely to comment to help them than downvote, regardless of how many downvotes the question already has.

With a *basic* poor question, 3 or 4 downvotes is enough to welcome them to the site with a nudge of how things are done, without it being too harsh.

However, if the question is poor *and* the user is being very lazy, and/or abusive, or even unnecessarily abrupt, I will downvote based on that.
Not as a way to "punish", as I'm not vindictive, but simply to show the user that they are *very much* in the minority and/or wrong.

Such users getting only a few downvotes tends to not be enough, they keep arguing "it's just userA and userB with the problem and have it in for me".
With 12 downvotes instead, the picture is painted differently and reflects more of the community "in general".

Users who care will reverse this question (maybe still remain negative) and try harder next time - no harm done it was 1 question.
If they do *not* care, then this is the sort of response they should get used to.

### Thresholds

There are no *official* thresholds as votes are up to *individual* users, but we do have our own personal thresholds.

For example *most* of us tend to not bother downvoting when a question is poor for average reasons and has a handful of downvotes (like 3 or 4).
This is enough to show the user they need to fix it etc.

This personal threshold fluctuates depending on the quality of the post. Again "average" bad posts (no code, duplicate, etc) tend to get 3 or 4, or maybe 5. But, if the post is really bad, and/or the OP gets negative towards other users in comments, then it can rein down the fires of hell. I've seen such scenarios bring 8 and 9 downvotes within a few mins of being posted.

New user or not.

Comment: "Don't handicap your children by making their lives easy" -- [Robert Heinlein](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272269/839601)

Answer (score 7):

The bigger question here is: why are you reading it? Why was the current score insufficient to warn you away from it?

- Is it a topic that interests you?
- Is it a topic that concerns you (off-topic / offensive)?
- Did it intrude upon a list of questions you monitor (favorite tag, newest, homepage)?
- Did someone give you a direct link for some reason?

Your vote - up or down - will help others in your position have a better idea of whether or not to bother reading the question. You should always vote based on how you perceive the quality and usefulness of the question itself, *regardless* of its current score... But whether or not you vote *at all* is something you might well decide based on how you came across the question; if you're far outside of your normal stomping grounds, you might decide to save your votes for questions closer to your area of interest.

Note that until the score hits -4, questions will still appear on the homepage - so withholding downvotes on lousy questions because of any score less than that is somewhat cruel to other readers: if you felt like you wasted *your* time by reading, you should leave some indication that would spare others that pain. That's not necessarily a reason to *withhold* your vote for questions below that threshold, merely a reminder that doing so for any score higher is a wee bit antisocial...

At the end of the day, your vote is your own to do with as you see right. Above all, be honest.