# How to find questions with very negative votes?

Tags: support, search, down-votes, research

In relation to [How many downvotes for a question are enough?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262289/how-many-downvotes-for-a-question-are-enough/262294#262294), where the accepted answer said, "If the question is poor and the user is being very lazy, and/or abusive, or even unnecessarily abrupt, I will downvote based on that....  If the post is really bad, and/or the OP gets negative towards other users in comments, then it can rain down the fires of hell."

That piqued my curiosity -- I haven't seen anything that bad yet.  How would I do a site search or a google search to find questions with very negative numbers?

Comment: @aparente001 Accepted answer does works but it will give you all negative posts with combination of questions and answers. In your case you want the questions only, please see my answer below for the same. Sorry for the dupe vote.

Comment: Marked question as a duplicate of has a wrong answer. I have posted my updated answer on that question specifically related to OP's question and his/her own accepted answer.

Comment: aparente001 Could you please check my answer and see if it resolves your question. I would like to "flag" this question not be marked as a duplicate of the one that has a wrong answer. As an OP your opinion matters the most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the method I often use.

- Go to the home page of the site.
- Click the Questions tab.
- Click the option to sort by votes.
- Scroll to the bottom and click on the final page number (see image).

[image]

This will show you the most down-voted questions at the very bottom. Each question up from there will have a better vote count.

Comment: You use this often? ... Why?

Answer (score 1):

You could also search it by entering either

**votes:..-1 is:question**

or

**score:..-1 is:question**

in the search box. Then, click on the "**votes**" tab.

Here is the direct links for each of the above listed search query: (performs the above *two* steps)

[**votes:..-1 is:question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=votes%3A..-1%20is%3Aquestion)

[**score:..-1 is:question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=score%3A..-1%20is%3Aquestion)

Now scroll down to the *bottom* of the page and click the last page given in the page-navigation bar before the "*next*" page tab. In my case it shows as "148". Now, all you have to do is navigate backwards from thereon. The above search query will *only* display the *questions* with *negative* votes. It's very important to include the **is:question** type option here otherwise search would result both i.e. questions and answers with negative votes.

> [image]

There used to be search limit of 6 queries per 60 seconds but it's no longer true as per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84311/please-increase-searches-per-minute/84337#84337).

P.S.

Since this question is marked as a *duplicate* of [Is it possible to search for down voted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156150/is-it-possible-to-search-for-down-voted-questions), I have posted my updated answer on that question specifically addressing to OP's question(s) and his/her own accepted answer.

Comment: I liked the other method better because the posts were sorted nicely, and I'm more likely to remember how to do that method.  But thank you.

Comment: @aparente001 That's fine with me I was more concern with duplicate question that has a wrong answer.