# Any purpose of [consulting] and [horror] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I don't think [consulting](/questions/tagged/consulting) and [horror](/questions/tagged/horror) serve any purpose on Stack Overflow. Before I start removing them from posts, I wanted to hear the community's view on them.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894206/is-this-define-statement-valid) seems like a valid target for the horror tag ;) (Please down downvote the link, [the OP knows its a bad question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197949/what-to-do-with-question-with-9-downvotes))

Comment: @RichardTingle It seems to have received 14 upvotes already!

Comment: @devnull The meta effect for a repentant OP I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [consulting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consulting) tag would be better suited to the [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), where the about page includes:

> ...professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about
>   software development

Consulting questions will largely be conceptual as one solution will not always be applicable to all clients.

The [horror](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/horror) tag seems to be doing a good job of scaring away any suitable questions, so I `+1` to abandon it.