# My question was deleted but I wasn't notified

Tags: feature-request, notifications, deleted-questions

Recently when I logged into StackOverflow, I found that my reputation has decreased. To find out the reason, I looked at my reputation history but couldn't find any reason why my reputation got decremented.

After some more research, I found, one of my question has been deleted from StackOverflow which I've flagged for deletion about 2 weeks ago, because of which all my associated reputation has been decremented.

I think, it would be better if a notification is sent to OP after or before deleting question especially if it has been a long time since flagging for deletion.

Actually, I flagged for deletion because of multiple downvotes. But after I've edited my question, the downvotes have been decreased and I don't want to delete my question now.

Comment: Well, if you flag a moderator to delete a question, you have to expect it to be eventually deleted.

Comment: Check the "show removed posts" box at the bottom of your reputation history. It is there.

Comment: Flag it again for non-deletion

Comment: @Emrakul I would not expect it to be deleted after about 2 weeks and with many activities in the meantime.

Comment: @UV-D When I try to undelete, I get "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted". :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to your question because it involves your expectations regarding what happened to the post once you flagged it;

I have undeleted your question for you. If you did not want it deleted, you should not have flagged for it to be deleted <sup>1</sup>. Since the question was closed for good cause and negatively voted, I decided to mostly do what your flag requested.

<sup>1</sup> The above statement assumes you are correct here that you flagged it for deletion.

Comment: Thanks. I did flagged for deletion and also I've asked this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197949/what-to-do-with-a-question-with-nine-downvotes regarding the deletion. Then, I edited question, now I'm fine with it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well I would have never done that if I were you!

> After some more research, I found, one of my question has been deleted from StackOverflow which I've flagged for deletion about a month ago, because of which all my associated reputation has been decremented.

If this was the reason, then bravo! There might be a +1 in the helpfull flags of your profile. I am not sure whether this would cause a plus one because I never flagged my questions or answers.

> Actually, I flagged for deletion because of multiple downvotes.

If you want to maintain a rep, then I guess you'll need to delete this question too. And keep deleting your questions and you will get banned from asking more questions. So stop doing so, and start editing the posts to make some sense in them!

> I think, it would be better if a notification is sent to OP after or before deleting question especially if it has been a long time since flagging for deletion.

Its not facebook you're talking about, its Stackoverflow. You cannot get live updates of everything! So I guess there is no chance for you to get updates from moderators about every action of theirs. But yes, you get live notifications of comments and other site achievements by you.

## What you should do

You should try to edit the questions instead of deleting them. And also there is a delete button on your posts too. You can use it! But keep it in mind that too many deletions or too many down votes would lead you to a ban!

And also, the post might have been deleted or closed due to voting. Or moderator have himself deleted the post. Because once you flag it, moderator takes action within 5 minutes or next to it. So a post deletion after a month, man were you hiding it? Or was it private or something :/

Comment: Moderator action, in my experience, has not always been so fast. There's quite a lot of flags they have to go through!

Comment: Yeah, but I can see a +1 in my helpfull flags just right after I come back from revisions! :) So I guess its a fast process.

Comment: The question had 9 downvotes and then I edited and now the question have 25 upvotes and 27 downvotes. And I asked this question before regarding what to do with downvoted question.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197949/what-to-do-with-a-question-with-nine-downvotes

Comment: And so you did got an answer there, didn't you?

Comment: Also, that the question had been edited and improved, because of which I didn't expect to be deleted after 2 weeks of flagging and activities.

Comment: well I have no guess for this, a moderator would help you! :)